# In admin css not loading

Tags: magento2, admin, css

[image: css not loading]

In my admin panel css is not working. If I use internal css in inspect element than its work and its working fine in localhost also.

Comment: Please deploy without static sign, you can set the Sign Static Files option to "No" in Store >> configuration >> developer >> Static Files Settings and redeployed the site.

Comment: Not working another option please.